# How to get results from Mysql database using WHERE if there is more than 1 criterion for identification?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

```
id  points    year        country
-----------------------------------
1   45        1998        Mexico
2   45        2000        Germany
3   47        2010        Russia
4   45        1970        China
5   49        2010        Austria
```

I wonder how can I take row results considering only 2 items from country column. For example only records where country is `Germany` and `Mexico`. When I try to get results where only 1 country is criterion the thing is easy:

```
 SELECT * FROM List WHERE Country='Mexico';
```

the result is:

```
id  points    year        country
-----------------------------------
1   45        1998        Mexico
```

but when I try to get results where 2 country items are criteria problems start. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico' AND Country='Germany';

SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico' AND 'Germany';

SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico','Germany';

SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico'AND WHERE country='Germany';
```

but no desired result:

```
id  points    year        country
-----------------------------------
1   45        1998        Mexico
2   45        2000        Germany
```

I understand that maybe I committed logical error because there is no single record where country is `Mexico` and `Germany` at same time, and sql maybe understands claim exactly that way, but, how to write correctly in sql language: Give me results for records where countries are `Mexico` and `Germany`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `IN` operator

```
 SELECT * FROM List WHERE Country in ('Mexico','Germany');
```

Comment: I like this much more than multiple `OR` chains!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `OR`.

So instead of

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico' AND Country='Germany';
```

it would be

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico' OR country='Germany';
```

`IN` is also a good function to use, especially if you've got multiple values that you want to check against but that's been covered in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `or` or `in`, you have been using `and` and asking mysql to find a row where country is both `Mexico` and `Germany` which is not true.

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE Country in ('Mexico','Germany');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE country='Mexico' OR Country='Germany';
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is using logic. Natural language is not.

When you say that you want the results for a list of countries you need to specify so. This request corresponds to an logical `or`. Since the name can be one or the other, both are correct.

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE Country = 'Mexico' OR Country = 'Germany'
```

To prevent further mistakes like these, I recommend that you look up logical operations in the docs (they are very good). [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions.html) or the [PostGres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions.html), both should be fine.